# +0-180 degrees of mesh layer are displaying as horizontal lines [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, grib, antimeridian, mesh

I have been trying to display weather data from ECMWF in QGIS on top of a base map, but half of the heatmap rendered from the mesh layer (imported via grib) displays as straight horizontal lines.

[image: Half of the world's windspeeds]

I am using QGIS 3.12.1
The base layer are XYZ tiles (Pseudo-Mercator EPSG:3857).
The overlay was imported from ECMWF in .grib format and imported as a mesh layer.

The two layers are clearly aligned, as the windspeeds clearly drop around the shape of South America and match the base layer precisely.
When I also display vector arrows for wind speed, they seem to cover the whole map:

[image: Vector images covering whole map]

Why is the heatmap imagery not displaying correctly at +0-180degrees, and how can I fix this?

Comment: If you import your `grib`-layer separately, i.e. without a base map, does it behave the same way?

Comment: How bizarre! Adding the grib layer first, without basemap, created a full map. However, the Americas are on the right and Eurasia is on the left.

Comment: The CRS shows up as 'unknown' and when I add the basemap back in, it is aligned with Eurasia, but the Americas hang off the map, on the left.

Comment: Original coordinates seems to be from 0 to 360 in longitude. It is grib1 or grib2? Most probably you will must transform it with gdal and config option CENTER_LONG 0. Can you share a single message grib file? About the unknown CRS, it is probably a geographic CRS based on a spheric datum, but users must analyze it as WGS84 geographic CRS (noop transformation).

Comment: see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28672

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust it using [CDO tools](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/):

```
cdo sellonlat,-180,180,-90,90 infile.nc outfile.nc
```